# PHP skip case sensitivity in file extension

Tags: php, file-exists

I have rows on my database table which some are not synchronized on the directory.

ex. on my table I have

```
image.png
```

but on my directory I have

```
image.PNG
```

now, Im having a problem to check if

```
file_exist
```

because of the case sensitivity.
I can't choose the option to synchronize my database and my files on the directory manually because it is too many.

May I know how can I used the file_exist that ignores the sensitivity of file types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Case Insensitive Version of file\_exists()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964793/php-case-insensitive-version-of-file-exists)

Comment: u can easy store files in lowercase or put them into DB with right name. Sure u can run throw the directory to find real names every time, but its WRONG solution, if u go throw thousands files this can drop php processes into Disk wait state and drop requests.

Answer (score 4):

For a more general solution, see the comments in the php docs:

[General Solution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#90256)

Which offers this version of the function:

```
/**
 * Alternative to file_exists() that will also return true if a file exists
 * with the same name in a different case.
 * eg. say there exists a file /path/product.class.php
 *  file_exists('/path/Product.class.php')
 *   => false
 *  similar_file_exists('/path/Product.class.php')
 *   => true
 */
function similar_file_exists($filename) {
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    return true;
  }
  $dir = dirname($filename);
  $files = glob($dir . '/*');
  $lcaseFilename = strtolower($filename);
  foreach($files as $file) {
    if (strtolower($file) == $lcaseFilename) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that checks both extensions and use it instead of file_exist directly.

Answer (score 1):

As i think, your root cause is due to following--
If your database have "image.png" and in directory "image.PNG" means there is some problem with your insert query.
It must be same in both the places. It better to advice to store file name in lowercase as Linux systems are case sensitive.