# Better way to rewrite an if else sequence

Tags: php

I want to ask what is the better to write this sequence of `if else` statements :

```
$dir = base_url()."assets/produits/";
  $img_src = $dir."none.png";

  if (!empty($row->nShape)) {
      $nom = $row->nShape;

  if (file_exists($dir.$nom.".JPEG")) {
      $img_src = $dir.$nom.".JPEG";
  }
  else
  if (file_exists($dir.$nom.".jpg")) {
      $img_src = $dir.$nom.".jpg";
  }
  else
  if (file_exists($dir.$nom.".jpeg")) {
      $img_src = $dir.$nom.".jpeg";
  }
  }
```

## The Full MVC Pattern

After implementing : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034937/5203821 answer

### The View File

```
<div class="container">
    <?=$message?>
    <?php
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $dir = base_url()."assets/produits/";
    $img_src = $dir."none.png";

    if (!empty($row->nShape)) {
            $nom = $row->nShape;

    $type = array(".JPEG", ".jpg", ".jpeg");

    foreach ($type as $ext) {
        if (file_exists($dir.$nom.$ext)) {
            $img_src = $dir.$nom.$ext;
            break;
        }
    }
}

    ?>

    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item col-md-4" target="_blanc" href="<?=site_url()?>/produits/detail/<?=$row->nProduct?>" title="<?=$row->sSort?>"><b><img src="<?=$img_src?>" alt="<?=$row->nShape?>" class="img-rounded product"><?=$row->sSearch?></b></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
     ?>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

### Model File

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Product_model extends CI_Model{

      function getProduct($product_id){
        $this->db->from('tequivalent')
                  ->where('nReference',$product_id)
                  ->join('tProduct','tProduct.nProduct=tequivalent.nProduct1');

                $query = $this->db->get();
                $ret['rows'] = $query->result();
                $ret['number'] = $query->num_rows();
                $ret['id'] = $product_id;

                return $ret;
      }
    }
```

### Controller File

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Produits extends CI_Controller {


    function index($product_id='')
    {

        if($product_id==NULL){
            redirect();
        }
        $this->load->model('Product_model');
        $query = $this->Product_model->getProduct($product_id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0));

        if($query['number']>0){
            $results['message']="<h2>Clique sur une Référence pour Plus de Detail</h2>";
            $results['number'] = $query['number'];
            $results['rows'] = $query['rows'];
        }else{
            $results['message'] = "<p>Oops! Y'a Aucun Résultat pour cette recherche</p>";
            $results['message'] .= "<a class='btn btn-lg btn-danger' href=".site_url().">Acceuil</a>";
            $results['number'] = $query['number'];
            $results['rows'] = $query['rows'];
            $results['id'] = $query['id'];
        }

        $this->load->view('constants/header');
        $this->load->view('produits',$results);
        $this->load->view('constants/footer');

}
}
```

The above code if the the full MVC Pattern since I'm using Codeigniter 
And thanks to all of you for your contributions

Comment: If you cannot standardize the way the files are saved, I would probably `glob()` the directory and do a case non-sensitive match against the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably consolidate the three `if` statements using a `foreach` loop:

```
dir = base_url()."assets/produits/";
    $img_src = $dir."none.png";

    if (!empty($row->nShape)) {
            $nom = $row->nShape;

    $type = array(".JPEG", ".jpg", ".jpeg");

    foreach ($type as $ext) {
        if (file_exists($dir.$nom.$ext)) {
            $img_src = $dir.$nom.$ext;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

By adding the extensions to an array can significantly reduce the redundant if statements.

Comment: it shows the none placeholder, and image file exists

Comment: Add `echo $img_src;` after `$img_src = $dir.$nom.$ext;` and see if you are getting any output.

Comment: it shows the `none.png` placeholder I've added the MVC pattern check it out

Comment: I've added the full code, you can check what I've done

Comment: Try adding the echo line that I mentioned (between `$img_src = $dir.$nom.$ext;` and `break`).

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: The code in my answer should do the same as your original code; It's unclear if the code is reaching that point or not, since you haven't specified the result of the echo.

Comment: Check the code linked and see [line 13](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f23571d47607c93b9c1a#file-gistfile1-txt-L13), and [line 18](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f23571d47607c93b9c1a#file-gistfile1-txt-L18) ... add that to your code as a test and report back the result. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f23571d47607c93b9c1a#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: Here's the results : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/489865/69395f3f59b138d1e9d23ecbf8f03fe4

Comment: Okay, so if you've added echo test two also, and that is not showing then your code is never reached there.

Comment: no, it's not performing the `foreach` loop it's just showing the variable at the top

Comment: It's not performing the foreach (where the `$ext` is set) because there's no echo test two — only echo test one is shown. So the fileexists is thinking that it's not one of the valid types. One more test you should do... is near echo test one do: `echo $dir.$nom;`

Comment: Check this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f3df38f09ed4476e8fea#file-gistfile1-txt-L14

Comment: The name is correct http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/489882/348c8beeee88305de04900a3dc3bfb17

Comment: Try the [second test](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f3df38f09ed4476e8fea#file-gistfile1-txt-L14) also, that's going to tell us if the extension is being added.

Comment: Yes the extension is being added : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/489891/f95aa0da9e7d3aacee33db3307161ab0

Comment: Okay, then I think the `$img_src` is getting set to `none.png` again after being set with `$ext`... Try your code like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/25abee2ef137cbd0a7a3. It moves the `$img_src = $dir."none.png";` out of the loop.

Comment: The Same problem, but when moving the $img_src = $dir.$nom.$ext; out of the condition it works, but without it we can't test if the file exists or not

Comment: Right, so one more thing you'll need to do is add an else: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f495055f9fbb0e9aabb3

Comment: I forgot a `}` after the else... https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f2f887254df4be84fb81

Comment: I mean it still showing the "none" placeholder, I think the `file_exists` is not working because when taking the `$img_src` out of the `if` statement working fine

Comment: You mean moving `$img_src` at the top or somewhere else? I thought you said it was working at some point... so not understanding what's wrong now. Perhaps it is the `fileexists`... maybe put and echo underneath that to see if it's ever reached.

Comment: That's the old code though... so of course there's not going to be any difference.

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm bothering you with me, but I do really need your help because I'm newbie and I need this to work : here is the results : http://s28.postimg.org/69e7lc8fx/Untitled.png

Comment: Sir check out this one its truly testing all the extension but it does not determiner whether it exists or not : http://i59.tinypic.com/21adda0.png

Comment: Yes, it seems like that

Comment: Your path might be missing a `/` is the only thing I can think of ...  Maybe try...:  `if (file_exists($dir."/".$nom.$ext)))`, although looking at your path it seems to already include it.

Comment: Yes, the me confusing, is that it gets file url and it exists but it does not test it

Comment: Yes! It's very odd, **and should work** — it even calls the else, so it's obviously testing something.. Right before the `if (file_exists...` do: `var_dump(file_exists($dir.$nom.$ext));`

Comment: Also try changing it to be `if (file_exists($dir.$nom.$ext) == 1) {`

Comment: it says `bool(false)`

Comment: That is very strange... do `var_dump(base_url()); var_dump($dir); var_dump($nom); var_dump($ext);`

Comment: That's what I got : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/489977/58efdd000aa548d84cdac4747be858d3

Comment: Did you try it like `if (file_exists($dir.$nom.$ext) == 1) {` also? There must be something we aren't seeing as to why it's returning `false` — because from everything I can see it's TRUE!

Comment: You know what... I don't think those files do exist on your server. Because in the last sample you showed with the actual webpage the image in just a placeholder, but there's no actual image.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964927/4126633), that ignores case:

```
function fileExists($fileName, $caseSensitive = true) {

    if(file_exists($fileName)) {
        return $fileName;
    }
    if($caseSensitive) return false;

    // Handle case insensitive requests            
    $directoryName = dirname($fileName);
    $fileArray = glob($directoryName . '/*', GLOB_NOSORT);
    $fileNameLowerCase = strtolower($fileName);
    foreach($fileArray as $file) {
        if(strtolower($file) == $fileNameLowerCase) {
            return $file;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

now you can iterate:

```
$allowedExtensions = ["jpeg","jpg"];

foreach($allowedExtensions as $ext){
     if(fileExists("youfFileName.$ext"),false){
         //do your code..
     }
}
```

Comment: But where I CAN DETERMINE A SPECIFIED DIRECTORY?

Comment: just send the full path "full/path/to/file/file.jpg"; the fileExists knows how to search inside the folder of the file using dirname($fileName);

Comment: But I can't use a function inside a foreach loop, checkout the above in the question

Comment: why you can't? I don't see the reason

Comment: `Cannot redeclare fileExists() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\dedax_new\application\views\produits.php:9)`