# Check if file (multiple extension possible ) exists?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, object, conditional-statements

I got  ascript which helps me to add some data into a csv file, based on the fact if a image is inside a folder or not (exits or not). Files are images, so I need to check if the file exists, and if it is a png, jpg, jpeg, gif.

So far it only check if it a JPG but I would like it to find the file exists if it's a PNG or JPEG or even GIF.

```
<?php
$columns = array("row1","row2","row3","row4","row5","row6","row7","row8","row9",
"row10","row11","row12","row13","row14","row15","row16","row17","row18"
);
$rootDir = "/path/to/images/folder/files";
$file = fopen("database.csv", "r") or die('fopen database failed');
$newFile = fopen("newdata.csv", "w") or die('fopen newdata.csv failed');
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 999999, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $row = array_combine($columns, $data);
    $filename = $row['row4'].".jpg"; // could be png or jpEg, or even gif
    if (file_exists("$rootDir/$filename")) {
        $row['image'] = .$filename; //also needs correct extension of image which exists.
        $row['small_image'] = .$filename;
        $row['thumbnail'] = .$filename; 
    }
    fputcsv($newFile, array_values($row), ";",'"' );
}
fclose($file);
fclose($newFile);
?>
```

Comment: You can make an array with the extensions and put `$filename = $row['row4'].".jpg"; // could be png or jpEg, or even gif
    if (file_exists("$rootDir/$filename")) {
        $row['image'] = .$filename; //also needs correct extension of image which exists.
        $row['small_image'] = .$filename;
        $row['thumbnail'] = .$filename; 
    }` in a for to check the extensions

Comment: suggestion: check [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php), it can give you better image type details than checking for extension

Comment: So, `row4` contains the root of the filename with no extension?

Comment: @mlclm, Is your question still actual for you? I have some good solution(if you're familiar with Linux shell)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// your code

$possible_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
$row = array_combine($columns, $data);
foreach($possible_extensions as $ext){
    $filename = $row['row4'] . "." . $ext;
    if (file_exists("$rootDir/$filename")) {
        $row['image'] = .$filename;
        $row['small_image'] = .$filename;
        $row['thumbnail'] = .$filename; 
        break;
    }
}
fputcsv($newFile, array_values($row), ";",'"' );

// your code
```

**Edited:**

If you want to perform case-insensitive `file_exists()` check then here's the solution,

The following `fileExists()` function returns the full path file if found, and `false` if not.

```
function fileExists($fileName, $caseSensitive = true) {

    if(file_exists($fileName)) {
        return $fileName;
    }
    if($caseSensitive) return false;

    // Handle case insensitive requests            
    $directoryName = dirname($fileName);
    $fileArray = glob($directoryName . '/*', GLOB_NOSORT);
    $fileNameLowerCase = strtolower($fileName);
    foreach($fileArray as $file) {
        if(strtolower($file) == $fileNameLowerCase) {
            return $file;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's the source:

- [PHP Case Insensitive Version of `file_exists()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964793/php-case-insensitive-version-of-file-exists)

And now your code,

```
// your code

$possible_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
$row = array_combine($columns, $data);
foreach($possible_extensions as $ext){
    $filename = $row['row4'] . "." . $ext;
    if ($filename = fileExists("$rootDir/$filename", false)) {
        $row['image'] = .$filename; //also needs correct extension of image which exists.
        $row['small_image'] = .$filename;
        $row['thumbnail'] = .$filename; 
        break;
    }
}
fputcsv($newFile, array_values($row), ";",'"' );

// your code
```

Comment: Mmmm... what about files with the extension `.JPG` rather than `.jpg` and other variations of case.

Comment: This is a bit expensive because you are looping through every filename four times.  It would be better to look at each filename, then run a loop checking for extension until it finds the right one.  At that point you'd only run through each four times if they were all the extension that was last in your array.

Comment: @MarkSetchell hmm, in that case it would be expensive because of the array size.

Comment: @JesseWilliams Not every time. Once it gets the file it will do it's operation and then break out from the loop, hence the `break` statement.