# Why different path in apache localhost and ubuntu server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, macos-sierra, ampps

I have project work in localhost 
my operator

```
MacOs sierra 10.12.5
Install Ampps sever version 3.6
Apache/2.4.25
PHP 5.6.30
```

i have a folder with path `/Applications/AMPPS/www/project/library/Utilities/Path.php`

php

```
var_dump(is_file('/Applications/AMPPS/www/project/library/utilities/path.php'));
```

alway return true but when i move to live hosting with operation

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
PHP 5.6.30-12~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04
```

and the path is different like /username/www/project/library/Utilities/Path.php

php

```
var_dump(is_file('/username/www/project/library/utilities/path.php'))
```

alway return false

i mean in my localhost the php function is_file or file_exits alway return true with filename or file folder first character is uppercase but in live host this alway return false , what different in this case ?

Comment: One file system is case sensitive, one isn't.

Comment: Linux filesystems are most often case sensitive.

Comment: how to fix that in php ? i need write autoload class .

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one file system is case sensitive and one isn't.

In Mac OS your default file system is [HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) where file names are not case sensitive, so `foo.php` and `Foo.php` are treated as equals.

In Ubuntu your default file system is (probably) [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) where file names are case sensitive, so `foo.php` and `Foo.php` are different files and can even co-exist in the same directory.

(Note: this applies to file *and* folder names, so `/foo/bar.php` and `/Foo/bar.php` could also be equals in one and not equals in the other)

I can see basically three options:

1. The best solution would be to always use (or require) the correct case for file and directory names.
2. If you absolutely need to deal with different/potentially incorrect cases, you might get away with an own solution (e.g. [PHP Case Insensitive Version of file_exists()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964793/php-case-insensitive-version-of-file-exists); basically: list all files in a directory and manually compare them). But in this case, would you load `foo.php` or `Foo.php` or `foO.php` when `FOO.php` is required and all three files exist?
3. If you have the necessary rights you could set up your Ubuntu to use a different file system where file names are case insensitive as well. Expect wry looks from linux guys.