# PHP: fetch file without check case sensitive

Tags: php, case-insensitive

I have a image named **Dark-Green.jpg** but the output of function is **DARK-GREEN.jpg** so the image is not displaying due to case-sensitive.

So how can I fetch the image?

**UPDATE**

Below is my output of the array.

```
$output = Array
(
  [WE05-5040*L] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
        [stitching_category] => 2
        [sku_image] => skuimages/WE05/DARK-GREEN.jpg
    )

)
```

Then I am using this array in **foreach** loop like below.

```
foreach ($output as $ok => $op) {
    $itemQty = $op['qty'];
    $itemImagePath = $op['sku_image'];
    echo "{$ok} has qty: {$itemQty} and the image as below.";
    echo "<img src='{$itemImagePath}' width='50%' />"
}
```

Comment: Just stick your arm deep into whatever the image is stuck in and wiggle it out. What I really mean is: Fetch from where, how? Show us your code.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, the code is simple. I am using the output of the function to fetch the image from the folder.

Comment: So it is fetching from the file-system, not from a database. Can you show us this simple code, and perhaps the function in question?

Comment: had to retract vote, but pos dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964793/php-case-insensitive-version-of-file-exists

Comment: @KIKOSoftware. Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: @treyBake. Tried but in case-insensitive, it returns false.

Comment: Thank you. So it is, in the end, a HTML link to an image, that does the fetching. Basically your output `DARK-GREEN.jpg` has lost information, namely the letter case of the image name. I see two possible solutions: 1. You reconstruct the information, for instance if all image names are camel-case you can do that. 2. Rename the image file. The best thing would, of course, be to not loose the information in the first place (if it ever existed).

Comment: 1: Not all images names are in camel-case. It would be in any case. 2: The images are uploaded by the frontend user so can't rename the image. Is there any solution by which I can do with my output without changing the image name and the function output?

Comment: Yes, there is, and it was already given by treyBake: You scan the folder, with `glob()` for image names similar to `DARK-GREEN.jpg`, while disregarding case, with `preg_grep()`, and use the first one of whatever comes out. This does however mean you will scan a whole directory for each HTML image link, and that's not very efficient (if there are much images in that directory).

Comment: Yeah, for now, this is the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getFile ($filename){
    $files = glob($dir . '/*');
    $filename = strtolower($filename);
    foreach($files as $file) {
       if (strtolower($file) == $filename){
            return $file;
        }
     }
     return  false;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964793/php-case-insensitive-version-of-file-exists is working for me as per treyBake's answer.

Comment: Ah great! Very similar