# Is Laravel blade '@include()' case-sensitive?

Tags: laravel, docker

I'm getting a "blade not found `shop.cart.favorites`" error when running in Docker on Ubuntu.  *(Therefore: "case-sensitive file system.")*

I suspect that the culprit is case-sensitivity.  The path to the blade file is:

```
 resources/views/Shop/Cart/favorites.blade.php
                 ^    ^
```

Did I guess correctly?

Comment: can you change the views in resources/views/shop/cart/favorites.blade.php ? Its case sensitive

Comment: Yes, that's probably a case sensitivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a little mistake bro...

Change in your Controller/Function where you defined the View .Like this.....

```
return View('Shop.Cart.favorites');
```

It will work..  Check it out..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of rendering a `View`, the `view()` method in Laravel checks to see if a Blade template file exists at the path provided [using](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d5deffa4d5468521e170cb7650019e5972b34c97/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L23) the PHP built-in method `file_exists()`.

Although the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) don't mention it at all, it has [long been observed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3964793/4468423) that this function can be case sensitive (typically on *nix-based filesystems, though not on Windows).  But since you don't necessarily know where your code will be run (e.g. if you are creating a package), best practice for cross-platform compatibility is to use only lowercase filenames for Blade template files.

Comment: I'd just note that it's only case sensitive *if* the filesystem is. We see quite a few questions here where it works on Windows locally, but not when deployed on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks folks. Indeed, that's the [ANSWER] I was expecting:  the underlying filesystem is case-sensitive, and therefore so is PHP (`file_exists()` *et al* ...), and therefore so is Laravel.  Blade file *and folder* names are case-sensitive.

---

Now ... here's a follow-on question:  is there a handy-dandy *plugin* for Laravel that might enable me to "skate around" this issue?  *(Yeah, I think I know what that answer will be, too.  But it doesn't hurt to ask ...)*